# Drools rule Error for Optaplanner- Reassign the same resources

Tags: drools, optaplanner

I am trying to write a rule for a vessel arrived at a berth. The vessel when arrived at a berth needs to get assigned a set of 'k' resources, where 'k' depends on the length of the vessel. The entire vessel stay time is divided into 'n' timeslots and the goal is to have the same 'k' resources in all the 'n' timeslots. The 'k' resources are an ordered and continuous values, and are assigned in the vessel arrival timeslot, I want the rest of the timeslots also to have the same order of the 'k' resources. I wrote the following rule for that and it doesn't work as I want it to work. Can someone help me with why this is happening?

```
    when
        ResourceAssignment($vessel: myVessel,
                           $resource: myResource, $resource != null,
                           $timeSlot: myWindow, $timeSlot == myVessel.getVesselArrivalTimeSlot(),
                           $id: id,
                           $resourcesRequired: myVessel.getResourcesRequired())
        ResourceAssignment(myVessel == $vessel,
                           id > $id,
                           eval(((id-$id) % $resourcesRequired) == 0),
                           myWindow.getTimeSlotId() > $timeSlot.getTimeSlotId(),
                           myResource != $resource,
                           $nextTimeSlot: myWindow.getTimeSlotId(),
                           $nextId: id,
                           $nextResource: myresource)
    then
        int resourceDiffPenalty =  Math.abs($nextResource.getResourceStart()-$resource.getResourceStart())*100;
        scoreHolder.addHardConstraintMatch(kcontext, -resourceDiffPenalty);
end
```

ResourceAssignment is my entity class and has the following definition:

```
public class ResourceAssignment {
    private Long id;
    private Vessel myVessel;
    private TimeSlot myWindow;
    private Resource myResource; // planning variable 1
    private QC myCrane; // planning variable 2
}
```

Comment: Just a comment, but your syntax can be simplified. This: `$resource: myResource, $resource != null,` is the same as this: `$resource: myResource != null,`. A lot of times if you simplify your syntax as much as possible, it becomes more evident where your logic problem is (and it makes the rule a lot easier to understand by other people, generally.)

Comment: Thanks @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas. Will change that.